# Erro ao gerar Key Store

Tags: android, android-studio

Estava seguindo os passos de um livro , para publicar um aplicativo , porém na hora de criar o JKS o android studio me retorna um erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está faltando a unidade no qual você quer salvar sua key no seu Key Store Path. Talvez seja: C:\Users ou D:\Users... Verifique ai no seu pc.

Comment: Coloquei e deu a mesma coisa @AckLay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve colocar o caminho completo no qual onde você quer salvar seu `.jks`. Se estive usando Windows, o caminho padrão é unidade `C:\` então ficaria desta forma:

```
C:\Users\paiva\Desktop\.....\novachave.jks
```

Verifique se o caminho se está correto.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa entrar em File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> app -> + -> colocar os dados da sua chave. Depois o generate apk deve funcionar.